# Can't find files downloaded inside gitlab runner

Tags: java, gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, unzip

I'm setting up GitLab CI for a gradle project. After downloading gradle, the unzip command reports that no zip file is found even though the download was successful. I added a an ls just to see the contents of the directory and my zip file was not present. Below is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build 

before_script:
  - cd /usr/lib
  - curl https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip -o gradle-2.10-bin.zip
  - unzip "gradle-2.10-bin.zip"
  - ln -s "/usr/gradle-2.10/bin/gradle" /usr/bin/gradle
  - rm "gradle-2.10-bin.zip"
  - export GRADLE_HOME=usr/lib/gradle-2.10
  - export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin

build_job:
  image: java:8
  stage: build
  script:
    - gradle -v
```

This the error output of the job

> $ unzip "gradle-2.10-bin.zip" unzip:  cannot find or open
>   gradle-2.10-bin.zip, gradle-2.10-bin.zip.zip or
>   gradle-2.10-bin.zip.ZIP. ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the full error output of that command, this is:

```
$ unzip "gradle-2.10-bin.zip"
Archive:  gradle-2.10-bin.zip
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of gradle-2.10-bin.zip or
        gradle-2.10-bin.zip.zip, and cannot find gradle-2.10-bin.zip.ZIP, period.
```

And if we check it that file is empty. If we do a `curl -I` on that url we get a 301 so you need to add the `-L` to that curl command to follow the redirection:

```
curl -L https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-bin.zip
```

Comment: here's the screenshot to the whole screen http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=25b447e8dd714a23e2b856cd82d2f0d4

Comment: Thanks. This was the solution. But now I'm getting gradle command not found. Is there a problem with the way I added it to the path?

Comment: Never mind, I found the problem. I missed a foward slach in export GRADLE_HOME=usr/lib/gradle-2.10